# Получить дату из строки

Tags: java

Доброго времени.
Есть стока: 2017-06-01T00:00:00.0000000+05:00
Какой сделать SimpleDateFormat что бы  получить Date?

Comment: А какие вы уже пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант только надо избавится от ':' в "+05:00" :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String datetime = "2017-06-01T00:00:00.0000000+0500";
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = format.parse(datetime);
        System.out.println(date);
  }
```